# Input/OutputStream between System.in and System.out - problem with readUTF() and writeUTF()

Tags: java, inputstream, outputstream, datainputstream, dataoutputstream

I'm trying to set up a very simple communication flow between System.in and System.out in Java, in order to understand how streams work.
I'm using DataInputStream for System.in and DataOutputStream for System.out, and they're communicating through readChar(), writeChar() and all.

Everything seems to work fine, until readUTF() is reached:

```
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(System.in);
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(System.out);
        
try {
  char c = dis.readChar();
  dos.writeChar(c);
            
  int i = dis.readInt();
  dos.writeInt(i);
            
  String s = dis.readUTF();
  dos.writeUTF(s);
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}       
try {
  dis.close();
  dos.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Console is displaying:

```
m /* note: keyboard input */
m
569
569
Hello
```

Looks like I can't find the way to indicate the end of the String, return isn't taken into account, nor \n etc. I've tried adding " too but same.

And I got a problem the other way around to, this code isn't displaying anything in the console:

```
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(System.in);
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(System.out);
        
try {
  dos.writeUTF("Hello");
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}       
try {
  dis.close();
  dos.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I've tried adding dos.flush() but nothing changes.
I think I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: I think [The readUTF() method of the DatainputStream, which reads the text data separately, will report an EOF exception. Why?](//stackoverflow.com/q/59691330) is a good duplicate. That the other question is about reading files isn't important, what "readUTF" does is and that is explained there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using [`DataInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/DataInputStream.html) and [`DataOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/DataOutputStream.html). The `readUTF` and `writeUTF` use a very specific serialization format, where the text is prefixed with a length indicator, and using modified UTF8. Console input doesn't use such format, so the first 4 characters of `Hello` are used to calculate the length, and you haven't input that many characters, and on output the 4 bytes used for the length of the string will likely generate garbage (as will the use of the modified UTF8, if you include codepoints that generate a modified format). You should probably use a [`BufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedReader.html) or [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html) instead and use the [`PrintStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html) `System.out` directly, or use a [`Console`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Console.html) obtained through [`System.console()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#console()).

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense! No simple way to read or write Strings throw DataIn/OutputStream then. I'll try to add a BufferedReader. My goal was really to use streams myself, not to use Scanner or System.out.print directly.

Comment: _"No simple way to read or write Strings throw DataIn/OutputStream then."_, basically you should only use those classes for data generated by its complement, they are not generic I/O streams (or readers/writers), but - for example - to implement a *binary* protocol.

Comment: Talking about binary protocol, imagine I got a server and and client for like a really simple FTP app. Server socket and client socket will  both have their own DataInputStream and DataOutputStream. If the client needs to communicate to the server something like 'GET filename' or 'PUT filename', would it be ok to use writeUTF() on the client DataOutputStream? And readUTF() on the server DataInputStream?

Comment: @lautreboutdumonde Not really, because the FTP protocol doesn't use the specific string serialization used by `readUTF` and `writeUTF`. If you would implement an FTP-like application, you could use them though, but then you can only use your own client/server combination because it would be a custom protocol.

Comment: @lautreboutdumonde `Hell` interpreted as binary bigendian is 1214606444; if you type 10 chars per second (few people can do more) for 8 hours every day, entering that string will take you 4217.38348611111 days, or about 12 years (not allowing for weekends, holidays, or any kind of leave). Assuming your computer stays up that long, of course.